Cookie not showing in Browsers storage under cookies
I am not sure I am understanding this correct or i can't get to work. I am testing in firefox.
I have a website mywebsite.com and an api myapi.com, mywebsite is a nextjs app and makes a redirect using window.location.href, this completes and is redirected to myapi.com, which then completes is redirected the mywebsite.com and has a cookie.
The myapi.com has cors headers including credentials and origin allow set to the mywebsite.com.
the cookie has a domain of myapi.com, httponly and secure.
I can see the cookie in the network tab on the browser development panel.
But the cookie isn't showing as stored in cookie section on the storage tab.
Because its cross origin, would it still be stored under mywebsite.com?
have i got the domain of the cookie right? (ie myapi.com)
If it is supposed to be stored here and if it is what else do i need to check to make sure its set?
Any suggestions would be appriciated.

The cookie is likely blocked as a third-party cookie. See https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd

it worked locally, so i don't think it would be although maybe. would prefer to get this working then i can change over

just been reading up, and i have confirmed my cookie is being store but its not stored in the mywebsite.com stoage under cookies which confused me, but will be looking as those resources thanks
